# Display JSON data in Flutter

Tags: node.js, json, flutter, dart

I want to display some data I am receiving from an API, this is the data I am receiving from my Node JS server:

```
[
    {
        "NAME": "Matematicas"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "Naturales"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "Ciencias Sociales"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "Lenguaje"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "Religion"
    }
]
```

This is how I am receiving the data in my front end (UPDATED WITH @Mofidul Islam):

```
Future<List<Subject>> fetchSubject() async {
  var url = Uri.http('localhost:8000', "/subjects");
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var token = prefs.getString('token');
  final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/subjects'),
      headers: {'x-access-token': token!});

  print(response.body);
  List<dynamic> list = "[" + response.body + "]" as List<dynamic>;
  List<Subject> subjectList = [];

  list.forEach((element) {
    subjectList.add(Subject.fromJson(element));
  });

  return subjectList;
}
```

This is the class to handle the incoming data (UPDATED WITH @Mofidul Islam):

```
class Subject {
  final String name;

  Subject({
    required this.name,
  });

  factory Subject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Subject(name: json['NAME'] as String);
  }

  parseJson(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Subject>((json) => Subject.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
}
```

This is my init state:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();    
    futureSubject = fetchSubject();
  }
```

This is how I am trying to display the data:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Materias',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Materias'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Subject>>(
        future: futureSubject,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Column(
              children: snapshot.data!
                  .map((subject) => Text(subject.name))
                  .toList(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          }
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
  

),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

However, the only thing being displayed when the page loads is:

```
Matematicas
```

I am trying to achieve 2 things:

1. Display the data in a list fashion like:

```
Subject Name 
Matematicas 
Naturales 
Ciencias Sociales 
Lenguaje Religion
```

2. Be able to use them as a link to another page when clicked

PD: If I remove the index access `[0]` on `return Subject.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);`
I get `Expected a value of type Map<String, dynamic> but got one of type List<dynamic>`

Any recommendations or guide on how to go through this?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop it

```
parseJson(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed
        .map<Subject>((json) => Subject.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
  }
```

and change your api call to this

```
Future<List<Subject>> fetchSubject() async {
  .....
  return parseJson(json.encode(response.body));
}
```

sorry for my english.

Comment: I tried this one, but where do I call `parseJson()` ? If I try to call it inside the `Future<List<Subject>>` method it says that the function is not defined. I apologize for taking so long to answer, I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one and return List from api method

```
Future<List<Subject>> fetchSubject() async {
  var url = Uri.http('localhost:8000', "/subjects");
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var token = prefs.getString('token');
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://localhost:8000/subjects'),
      headers: {'x-access-token': token!});
List<dynamic>list=response.body as List<dynamic>;
      List<Subject>subjectList=[];
        
      list.forEach((element){
        subjectList.add(Subject.fromJson(element));
      });

      return subjectList;
  
}
```

refactor UI like this

```
Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Subject>>(
            future: futureSubject,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(children: snapshot.data.map((subject)=>Text(subject.name)).toList(),);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        )
```

Comment: I tried this one from inside the api method `Future<Subject>fetchSubject()` , I am returning it this way `return subjectList[0]` and when I run the app I get `Expected value ot type List<dynamic> but got one of String`. And if I try to return it the way you mentioned, `subject[0].name` I get this error in the return clause: `A value of type 'String' can't be returned from the function 'fetchSubject' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<Subject>>'.`. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You should return subjectList not subjectList[0] and function return type should be Future<List< Subject>> not Future<Subject> and refactor your ui to receive List<Subject>

Comment: I have modified my answer .Please have a look if its helps @Irwin

Comment: Thank you, tried the updated example, I get `Expected a value of type List<dynamic> but got one of String`. I have to mention that I had to add a `!` in `return Column(children: snapshot.data.map((subject)=>Text(subject.name)).toList(),);` Although I know theres something I am doing wrong...

Comment: element is not String .Its Map<String,String> like {"Name":"Mathermaticts"}

Comment: You are correct, I updated the code based on your recommendations, maybe you can catch what I am missing... @Mofidul Islam

Comment: Your problem is here I guess List<dynamic> list = response.body as List<dynamic>;Can you check  print(response.body) this should be like [
    {
        "NAME": "Matematicas"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "Naturales"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "Ciencias Sociales"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "Lenguaje"
    },
    {
        "NAME": "Religion"
    }
] else please do like this List<dynamic> list = "[" + response.body + "]" as List<dynamic>;

Comment: The print of the response.body shows like this: `[{"NAME":"Matematicas"},{"NAME":"Naturales"},{"NAME":"Ciencias Sociales"},{"NAME":"Lenguaje"},{"NAME":"Religion"}]`. 

I updated the line with `List<dynamic> list = "[" + response.body + "]" as List<dynamic>;`

Getting the same error `Expected a value of type List<dynamic> but got one of String`. Updating also the main thread of the question with this

Comment: Do you think I would need to change the Text widget in the UI for a ListView? @Mofidul Islam